# How can I split the following string into a string array

Tags: c#

I want to split the following:

```
name[]address[I]dob[]nationality[]occupation[]
```

So my results would be:

```
name[]
address[I]
dob[]
nationality[]
occupation[]
```

I have tried using `Regex.Split` but can't get these results.

Comment: You don't seem to have any sort of delimiter you can use. Do you have additional examples, so we can see the general pattern - one example is rarely enough.

Comment: Stupid question: can you change string generator instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Regex.Split` with the following regex:

```
(?<=])(?=[a-z])
```

which will split between a closing square bracket on the left and a letter on the right. This is done using [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They don't consume any characters of the match so in this constellation they're pretty handy to match between letters.

Basically it means exactly what I wrote: `(?<=])` will match a point in the string preceded by a closing bracket, while `(?=[a-z])` matches a point in the string (both zero-width, i.e. *between* characters) where a letter follows. You can tweak that a little if your input data looks different from what you gave us in the question.

You could also simplify it a little, at the expense of readability, by using `(?<=])\b`. But I would advise against that since `\b` is tied to `\w` which is a really ugly thing, usually. It would work *roughly* the same, but not quite, as `\b` in this context amounts to `(?=[\w])` and `\w` matches a lot more things, namely decimal digits and an underscore too.

Quick PowerShell test (it uses the same regex implementation since it's .NET underneath):

```
PS> 'name[]address[I]dob[]nationality[]occupation[]' -split '(?<=])(?=[a-z])'
name[]
address[I]
dob[]
nationality[]
occupation[]
```

Just for completeness, there is also another option. You can either split the string *between* the tokens you want to retain, or you could just collect all matches of tokens you want to keep. In the latter case you'll need a pattern that matches what you need, such as

```
[a-z]+\[[^\]]*]
```

or [what Dennis gave as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14398406/73070) (I just tend to avoid `\w` and `\b` except for quick and dirty hacks or golfing since I maintain that they have no useful application). You can use that with `Regex.Matches`.

Generally both approaches can work fine, it then depends on whether the split or the match pattern is easier to understand. And for `Regex.Matches` you'll get `Match` objects so you don't actually end up with a `string[]` if you need that, so that'd require `.Select(m => m.Value)` as well.

In this case I guess neither regex should be left alone without a comment explaining what it does. I can read them just fine, but many developers are a little uneasy around regexes and especially more advanced concepts like lookaround often warrant an explanation.

Comment: Beat me to it. TIL you don't always need to escape a `]`.

Comment: Aah, I wasn't familiar with that abbreviation :-)

Comment: Do you mind breaking down the regex to components and explain each (i.e. how and why this works)?

Comment: @Joey: Expresso returns NULL's as matches on the source string.

Comment: Dennis, of course. The regex marks split points, not matches. If you want matches, you'll need `[a-z]+\[[^\]]*]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
text.Split(new Char[] { ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s + "]").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex pattern:

```
\w*\[\w*\]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression should be fine. You can also consider to catch the opening and the closing square brackets with string.IndexOf, for example:

```
IEnumerable<string> Results(string input)
{
    int currentIndex = -1;
    while (true)
    {
        currentIndex++;
        int openingBracketIndex = input.IndexOf("[", currentIndex);
        int closingBracketIndex = input.IndexOf("]", currentIndex);

        if (openingBracketIndex == -1 || closingBracketIndex == -1)
            yield break;

        yield return input.Substring(currentIndex, closingBracketIndex - currentIndex + 1);
        currentIndex = closingBracketIndex;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string inputString = "name[]address[I]dob[]nationality[]occupation[]";    
var result = Regex.Matches(inputString, @".*?\[I?\]").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value).ToArray();
```